# how to implement a recursive traversal inside an iterator generator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

Say I have a tree, something like the following, in javascript:

```
let rootNode = {name:'', children:[
                   {name:'0', children:[
                       {name:'00', children:[]},
                       {name:'01', children:[
                           {name:'010', children:[]},
                       ]},
                       {name:'02', children:[]},
                   ]},
                   {name:'1', children:[
                       {name:'10', children:[]},
                   ]},
               ]};
```

And I want to do a preorder traversal on it, I could do it like this:

```
function preOrderTraversalRecursive(rootNode, visitNodeCallback) {
    function recurse(node) {
        visitNodeCallback(node);
        for (let childNode of node.children)
          recurse(childNode);
    }
    recurse(rootNode);
};
console.log("Pre-order traveral, recursive:");
preOrderTraversalRecursive(rootNode, function visitNodeCallback(node) {
    console.log("  '"+node.name+"'");
});
```

which gives the expected output:

```
  Pre-order traveral, recursive:
    ''
    '0'
    '00'
    '01'
    '010'
    '02'
    '1'
    '10'
```

Now let's say I want to do the same thing ES6 generator-style.  I thought that would look like this:

```
function *preOrderGeneratorIteratorRecursive(rootNode) {
    function recurse(node) {
        yield node;
        for (let childNode of node.children)
            recurse(childNode);
    }
    recurse(rootNode);
};
console.log("Pre-order generator iterator, recursive:");
for (let node of preOrderGeneratorIteratorRecursive(rootNode)) {
    console.log("  '"+node.name+"'");
}
```

But apparently that's illegal: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word` at the `yield`.

Disappointing!  Is there some syntax I'm missing?
What's the cleanest way to make a generator expressing this algorithm?
Perhaps using some helper library?

I know I can use an explicit stack as follows, but this isn't satisfactory for several reasons:
(1) the logic is obscured to the point where there's no
readability advantage to using the generator; might as well go back
to the recursive-with-callback version, and
(2) it's not really the same algorithm, since it's iterating backwards
over each node.children. In particular, this means it won't work
if node.children is some other kind of iterable, perhaps from another generator.

```
function *preOrderTraversalIteratorGeneratorExplicitStackCheating(rootNode) {
  let stack = [rootNode];
  while (stack.length > 0) {
    let node = stack.pop();
    yield node;
    for (let i = node.children.length-1; i >= 0; --i) // backwards
      stack.push(node.children[i]);
  }
} // preOrderIteratorGeneratorExplicitStackCheating
console.log("Pre-order traveral of tree with explicit stack, cheating:");
for (let node of preOrderTraversalIteratorGeneratorExplicitStackCheating(rootNode)) {
  console.log("  '"+node.name+"'");
}
```

To be clear: I'm not interested in a special-purpose helper that hides the horrible details
of an explicit-stack traversal implementation.
I want to know if there's a way to write iterator generator algorithms clearly, even if they happen to be recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed provided for with the `yield*` operator. Essentially, you need to think of this as one generator delegating its functionality to another. (Indeed, you can delegate to any iterable value.)

For example, you could do this:

```
function *pointlessGenerator() {
    yield* [1, 2, 3, 4];
}
```

This would yield `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`, because `yield*` runs the iterator and yields all of that iterator's values in turn. Exactly the same behaviour takes place if you pass a generator.

In your case you want to make `recurse` a generator and then call it with `yield*`:

```
function *preOrderGeneratorIteratorRecursive(rootNode) {
    function *recurse(node) {
        yield node;
        for (let childNode of node.children)
            yield* recurse(childNode);
    }
    yield* recurse(rootNode);
};
console.log("Pre-order generator iterator, recursive:");
for (let node of preOrderGeneratorIteratorRecursive(rootNode)) {
    console.log("  '"+node.name+"'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `recurse` function, in which you're trying to use `yield`, is not declared as a generator. That's why you're getting a syntax error. It would need to be

```
function preOrderGeneratorIteratorRecursive(rootNode) {
    function* recurse(node) {
        yield node;
        for (let childNode of node.children)
            yield* recurse(childNode);
    }
    return recurse(rootNode);
}
```

or simply

```
function* preOrderGenerator(node) {
    yield node;
    for (let childNode of node.children)
        yield* preOrderGenerator(childNode);
}
```

Comment: The original way I wrote it, `recurse` wasn't intended to be a generator; it was just part of the implementation of the enclosing generator's control flow. I.e. the `yield`s inside it were intended to yield from the enclosing generator; it looked to me like that was the only possible meaningful interpretation of what I wrote.   However, upon further thought, I see that it would be problematic for the language to allow that: e.g. if an instance of the inner function's scope lives longer than the generator.  I guess the cases I'm interested in can be expressed almost-as-clearly using yield*.

Comment: I think you're missing a `*` on `preOrderGeneratorIteratorRecursive` in your first code block.  Also `return recurse(rootNode);` needs to be changed to `yield* recurse(rootNode);`, as in @lonesomeday's answer.

Comment: @DonHatch Yes, it would be very problematic, and is therefore not allowed (not even a matter of "living longer", but just of being called outside of the generator - control flow could be severely harmed. Being not allowed, you get a syntax error when trying to use `yield` in a non-generator function.

Comment: @DonHatch No, I'm not missing it, `preOrderGeneratorIteratorRecursive` (what a horrible name! :P) is deliberately a normal function. It just returns a generator (created by calling `recurse(…)`), pretty much indistinguishable in behaviour from an actual generator function.